# When search input is :focus make the surrounding div black

Tags: javascript, css, forms, search

On my site [unbotttled.com](http://www.unbotttled.com)

in the menu the surrounding div of the search form turns black when I hover over it. What I want is when the input field is clicked on or in focus I want the surrounding div to turn black even when I stop hovering. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: If you posted some html/css that would be great, I should not have to dig through your website to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use jQuery to find when it is in focus and set the background color to your liking:

HTML:

```
<div id="out"><form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.unbotttled.com/">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="">

</form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.field').focus(function() {
    $('#out').css('background-color','black');
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yZhC3/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript for this, as far as I know.

with jquery:

```
$search = $('.my-search-bar-input'); 
$search.on(':focus', function () {
    $search.parent().addClass('.selected');
})
.on(':blur', function () {
    $search.parent().removeClass('.selected);
});
```

and css:

```
.my-search-container.selected, .my-search-container:hover {
    background-color: #333; // Your color
}
```

Something like that should work.